# Extension on Array where element is a generic struct in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

How would one extend an array of structs that have a generic type? Please see the below code for what I am trying to do.

```
struct MyStruct<T: MyProtocol> {
   ...
}

extension Array where Element: MyStruct<T> { // Not sure if T is supposed to be on this line.

    func doWork() -> [T] {
        ...
    }
}
```

Basically, how would I write the extension to have a method return an array of the generic type passed into the struct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to create a protocol with an associated type:

```
protocol MyGenericStructProtocol {
    associatedtype GenericParameter
}
```

Let your struct adopt the protocol, either directly, or using an extension:

```
extension MyStruct: MyGenericStructProtocol {
    typealias GenericParameter = T
}
```

Now you can reference the generic type inside your extension of Array:

```
extension Array where Element: MyGenericStructProtocol {
    func doWork() -> [Element.GenericParameter] {
        return []
    }
}
```

Check out a fully working example on [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/Dev1an/2d5c87a2a5b68ab2c8af2889dd6e2148)